# How can I dynamically load options into a select list?

Tags: forms, 6

I'm creating form using `drupal_get_form` and I'm using the following code for creating a select list:

```
$form['select-user-group'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select a group'),
  '#options' => array(
    '' => t('-- Select a user group --'),        
  ),
  '#ajax' => array(
  'event' => 'load',
  'callback' => 'selectuser_ajax_callback',
  'method' => 'replace',
);
```

and then I'm trying to define a function like following to dynamically add options to the select list:

```
function selectuser_ajax_callback() {

  db_set_active('drupal');

  $result = db_query("select * from {content_type_usergroup}");
  $record = db_fetch_object($result);

  $str = '<select>';
  while ($obj = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $str .= '<option value=' + $obj->vid + '>' + $obj->field_p_group_name_value + '</option>';
  }
  $str .= '</select>';

  echo $str;
}
```

But it's not working. How to make this function work properly to populate the select list `'#options`?

Comment: <select> in while loop will load <select> for every record.You should remove it from while loop

Answer (score 4):

For just populating select list options, you don't need to go through an Ajax approach! Simply write a separate function and write your database query inside it and then just call that function in `'#options'` of your `$form['select-user-group']`.

For example for displaying all node types in a select list you can use the following function:

```
function get_node_type_info() {

  $wizard_plugins = node_type_get_types();

  $options = array();

  foreach ($wizard_plugins as $key => $wizard) {
    // Don't forget the $ before wizard
    $options[$key] = $wizard->name;
  }

  return $options;
}
```

And then use this function to populate the `'#options'` like so:

```
$form['display_options'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Component Type'),
  '#options' => get_node_type_info(),
);
```

Comment: can you provde a full sample to load option to select box , here node_type_get_types() function is not defined .

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_types/7